# How can I see print() statements in behave (BDD)

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

Context: I am using Python with Behave (BDD).

Whether I run my tests from the command line (behave) or from a custom main(), the behavior is the same: the test runs and the only output that I see in the console is the standard BDD report.

My tests include print() statements that help me debug my code.  However, none of these print statements are being displayed in the console output when I run behave.

Is there any way we can **have "behave" display the print statements in our code?**

My Main()

```
config = Configuration()
if not config.format:
    default_format = config.defaults["default_format"]
    config.format = [ default_format ]
    config.verbose = True
r = runner.Runner(config)
r.run()

if config.show_snippets and r.undefined_steps:
    print_undefined_step_snippets(r.undefined_steps)
```

My test.feature file:

```
Feature: My test feature with the Behave BDD
    Scenario: A simple test
    Given you are happy
    When someone says hi
    Then you smile
```

My test_steps.py file:

```
from behave import given, when, then, step, model

@given('you are happy')
def step_impl(context):
    pass

@when ('someone says {s}')
def step_impl(context, s):
    context.message = s
    print("THIS IS NEVER DISPLAYED IN THE CONSOLE")
    pass

@then ('you smile')
def step_impl(context):
        assert(context.message == "hi")
```

Comment: check behave's command line arguments: https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html

Comment: Also u need to set junit to False, because in behave/configuration.py u can see - it stderr_capture, stdout_capture and log_capture to True

Comment: A better approach than using prints is to fail the test manually with something like: test.fail(f'Could not run test:{meaningful_data}')

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I figured it out after spending more time reading the documentation.  It is actually quite simple.  By default, `behave` does **not** display any output (i.e. by using `print()`) unless there is a failure in the test.
To force displaying all output regardless of the outcome of the test (pass/fail), all you need is to change some of the default settings.  The easiest way to achieve that is to create a file named `behave.ini` in the root of your project's directory and put the following:

Filename: **`behave.ini`**

```
[behave]
stderr_capture=False
stdout_capture=False
```

Next time you run your behave tests, you will see all outputs from your debug statements whether your tests pass or fail.

Comment: It does not solve all. I made a test with three line printed in a step which is called multiple times during my tests. The 3 lines are correctly printed for the two firsts tests, then only the third line remains visible in the following tests.

Answer (score 50):

from command line, you can use the following:

`--no-capture` for any stdout output to be printed immediately.

`--no-capture-stderr` for any stderr output to be printed immediately.

Comment: I found that when I call it with behave I also need -s, along with --no-capture.

Answer (score 42):

The first thing to do is to prevent capture of `stdout` (and maybe also `stderr`) as explained by [Xuan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28551235/1906307) or [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291321/1906307).

However, there's a further complication that will stump people who are not aware of it. By default, `behave` outputs its report in color. This is problematic because the way it works is that when it runs a step, it first prints out the line of the step in a neutral color that indicates it does not yet know whether the step has passed or not. Once the step has finished, it uses escape codes to overwrite the previous line with a new color. If you don't do something to work around it, `behave` may simply **overwrite what your `print` statement produced**, and it may be difficult to figure out what happened.

In the following illustrations, I'm going to put the color in brackets at the end of the line. If you do not use `print`, the step "do something" would appear like this, before it is executed:

```
When do something [gray]
```

And once executed it would be replaced with a green line:

```
When do something [green]
```

`behave` outputs an escape sequence that makes the terminal go up and overwrite the line with a new color. No problem there.

If you put `print "foo"` in your step, the terminal would contain this, just before the step is completed:

```
When do something [gray]
foo
```

And then when the step completes successfully this is what you'd see on the terminal:

```
When do something [gray]
When do something [green]
```

The same escape sequence has caused `behave` to overwrite the output produced by the `print` statement.

I've used two methods to work around the issue in addition to turning off `stdout` capture:

1. Use the `--no-color` option. This turns off the escape sequences and your  `print` statements should produce visible output.
2. Add a few extra newlines at the end of a `print`. So `print "foo\n\n"`, for instance. `behave` will overwrite a useless blank line instead of overwriting the information you want. This is what I end up doing most often because I never invoke `behave` directly and adding a single additional option to `behave`'s invocation, or editing a settings file is more cumbersome than just adding a few newlines to `print`.

Comment: the `--no-color` option what the key to me seeing output - I was stumped as to why I couldn't see any until I read this answer

Comment: Me too, `--no-capture --no-color` for the win!

Answer (score 5):

`behave.ini` doesn't work for me.
I choose to

- use the `--no-capture` argument to see `print()` statements in the console (though the last `print()` never going to appear, and I don't know why), or
- redirect the output to a file so I can see all the stdout lines there to debug.

Comment: clarification: how exactly did you set `--no-capture` ?

Comment: I don't set it, I use it as a parameter in the command line when I run behave

Comment: To see the last `print()` statement I had to run `print()` statement in `afer_step` in `environment.py`

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that the lines got eaten. This worked (hack).

```
print(my_variable, "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

One other way to view the last line of stdout/stderr even when using coloured output with --no-capture; place the following in your environment.py:

```
def after_step(context, step):
    print()
```

That way the empty line gets eaten, not the one you actually want to see.

Comment: I had followed the steps above but none of the print statements printed to the console. Adding an empty print statment fixed the issue. A bug in behave?

Answer (score 1):

one way: is to use
--no-capture on cmd prompt

second way:
create a behave.ini file in project directory. add following

[behave]
stdout_capture = no

Answer (score 1):

this works 100% !!!
add behave.ini to project folder:

```
[behave]
color = no
stdout_capture = no
stderr_capture = no
log_capture = no
```

## color and stdout_capture are the most critical to print out!

run as:

```
$ behave my.feature
```

OR
not having behave.ini:
run as:

```
$ behave --no-capture --no-color my.feature
```