# Behave , print out scenario number

Tags: bdd, python-behave

Context: I am using Python with Behave (BDD).
My .feature file look like this:

```
@ISA-75 
@ISA-76
@1
@1.1
Scenario: A user will be able to enter an email address to receive a notification when a requested archive is complete.
  Given ...
  When ...
  Then ...
```

The output of the run doesn`t contain the @1 or @1.1 information.
There is any way to tell behave to print out that information at run time?

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on how you are making your assertions. But you can implement it from info found in their [docs](http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/context_attributes.html?highlight=context). I set a behave.ini as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291321) so print appears and then added this to environment.py file.

```
def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    if context.failed == True:
        print(context.scenario, 'failed. Here are the tags:')
        for tag in context.tags:
            print(tag)
```

You might just way to use a try/catch on your assertion and run the last lines on exception.