# How to print in python and behave

Tags: python, python-behave

```
@then('I should be able to able to print with id "{el_id}"')
def step_impl(context, el_id):
    if is_element_id_there(context, 'el_id'):
        print(get_element_text_id(context, 'el_id'))
    else:
        raise Exception('Element with id: ' + el_id + ' not found')
```

I also used other way of printing by defining variable

```
@then('I should be able to able to print with id "{el_id}"')
def step_impl(context, el_id):
    if is_element_id_there(context, 'el_id'):
        var = get_element_text_id(context, 'el_id')
        print(var)
    else:
        raise Exception('Element with id: ' + el_id + ' not found')
```

Note: I already added `--no-colors` and `--no-capture` in my bash profile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see print() statements in behave (BDD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150404/how-can-i-see-print-statements-in-behave-bdd)

Comment: Did you add a behave.ini file?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291321/3838981

Answer (score 2):

Add a newlines at the end of a print:

```
print(get_element_text_id(context, 'el_id') + '\n')
```

or

```
var = get_element_text_id(context, 'el_id')
print(var + '\n')
```